# Dividing the page and Viewing the division

Tags: html, css

I just want to view the divisions I have done on the page, but nothing is visible on the page. What is wrong with my code?

I just want that what I have divided should be shown on the page without content. I'm using chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .main {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#029CC9, #005077); /* For Safari */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#029CC9, #005077); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#029CC9, #005077); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
            background: linear-gradient(#029CC9, #005077); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
        }

        .main .header .icon {
            width: 90%;
            margin-left: 5%;
        }

        .main .header .menu {
            width: 90%;
            margin-left: 5%;
        }

        .main .content {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <div class="menu"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your divs are probably present, they just don't have any actual content in them. You need to add text or other visual elements to see anything

Comment: How can I do this without content?

Comment: You can look at the divs by right-clicking in the window and pressing `Inspect Element` - then searching for the divs you created. [since you're using Chrome]

Comment: I've already done that, but my question is how can i view divisions without content?

Comment: I've used height in `.main`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `&nbsp;` within the div elements to see the backgrounds you can see the colors without having any actual content in it.

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="icon">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="menu">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u tell me why it's not on whole page even if I have done width and height 100%

Comment: Try to set the height with a px. i set it to 500px and it showed up quite large. Also, you may want to add a `background` color to the icon and menu tags as well since you can't see them at all. I used red `background:#900;` and green `background:#090;` to display them easilly on top of the blue

Comment: As for the full height, see this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043830/div-stretch-100-page-height-regardless-of-content)

Comment: This is very helpful, but why can't I do it using percentage? What my concept is that percentage feature is good as it will be flexible with all resolution.

Comment: That link is again helpful :)

Comment: you can use percentages... you just need to set up the page to accommodate it completely. simply add `html,body{height:100%}` and you should be all set with the full page background

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a basic border around the `main` div and color it green. You can do similar things for the others to show where each div is placed.

```
.main {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: What if i want it on whole page? how can i do it with percentage in width?

Answer (score 0):

Change the .main into an id.

Replace .main with #main respectively.

Comment: I tried it myself, the blue background showed up with a container inside. You try it first, then let me know again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the `div` portion without adding text ,you have to mention particular `height` .

```
.main .header .icon {
     width: 90%;
     margin-left: 5%;
     height: 30px;
}
```